# Graph api not returning more than the 500 images

Tags: facebook-graph-api

IVe been using the graph api to download large albums (over 5000 images), ive been using the offset and limit parameter to download 25 images at a time. when i reach 500 no images get returned (tested this on the api expolrer as well), if i try 490 then it will only return 10. Anyone know a way around this limit?

Comment: better use paging instead of an offset: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging - you should also increase the limit, for example, to 100 instead of 25

Comment: ill look into that, thanks